# The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following method inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
public SystemInformation GetSystemInfo(int pagesize)           
{
    var d = DateTime.Today;
    SystemInformation s = new SystemInformation()
    {                            
       DeleteNo = tms.TechnologyAudits.Where(a => (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateTimeEnd.Date) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d) && a.AuditAction.Name.ToLower() == "delete")).Count(),

    };
    return s;
}
```

But the above is raising the following exception:-

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

Comment: check here ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949892/using-datetime-in-dynamic-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `a.DateTimeEnd.Date` that cannot be translated. The equivalent is `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateTimeEnd)` . You do not need/cannot use both.

[DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value
>   set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00)

[EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> The input date with the time portion cleared.

Comment: thanks a lot ,, i understood the problem ..

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to Entities cannot translate most .NET Date methods (including the casting you used) into SQL since there is no equivalent SQL.

In your case LINQ cannot translate this

```
(EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateTimeEnd.Date)
```

The solution is to cast the object outside the LINQ statement and then pass in a value.

Comment: but how i can do this in my case , as i am using the date inside a where,, so i can not cast the object ouside my where ()? can u advice ?