# How to execute a LINQ to Entities query, pulling values from an existing resultset variable instead of against the DB

Tags: stored-procedures, orm, jqgrid, entity-framework-6, dynamic-linq

To provide some context, I'm using jqGrid to conduct a server side search on a datetime field, truncating the time portion server side, and then fetching results via a stored procedure. This is being done using System.Dynamic.Linq, which I've modified slightly as per this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949892/using-datetime-in-dynamic-linq-to-entities). I'm using EF6 Code First approach. The relevant portion of the code looks something like this:

```
//For matching date instead of datetime values
if (wc.Clause.Contains("Date"))
{
    wc.Clause = wc.Clause.Replace("DeliveryDate", "DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DeliveryDate)");
}
results = dataFileDB.Database.SqlQuery<Document>("exec [dbo].[sp_getDocumentDetails]").AsQueryable().Where(wc.Clause, wc.FormatObjects);
```

The problem I'm having is that because the query is fetched using a stored procedure, I get an exception on the last line saying

> System.NotSupportedException: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(Nullable`1 dateValue)

In other places where I've used a lambda query to fetch directly from the entity itself and apply the where clause filter, the filtering is done correctly.

What I was trying to do (and I'm not sure if this is possible but...) was run an entity query against the `results` variable and apply the where clause to that variable but I've had no luck. Is this the right way to go or is there another approach I could take?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... I was overcomplicating things too much.

I just converted the `DateTime` field to a `Date` field when returning it via the stored procedure. Doing so no longer required me to use the `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` method, thereby resolving my issue.

Hope this helps someone else!